# Pass associative array to Javascript function

Tags: javascript

How can I pass associative array in the below code. I dont wish to create a variable

```
uiDialog([MyURL,null,'GET'],false);
```

Some thing like this

```
 uiDialog([url:MyURL,data:null,method:'GET'],false);
```

I know I can do something like

```
var arr = new Array(5);
  arr["000"]="Rose";
  arr["4"]="Ltd";
```

And pass this array but I am not interested in that I want a one line code

**UPDATE**
It seams there is no one line solution but if object is not a problem i.e u cant use array function or length you can try this answer [Pass associative array to Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888921/pass-associative-array-to-javascript-function/6888938#6888938)

Comment: Looks like you'd better first read up on javascript arrays vs javascript objects. Try http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 uiDialog({url:MyURL,data:null,method:'GET'},false);
```

Comment: This is passing an Object that is not an Array. There are subtle differences.

Comment: how can do for a array not object

Comment: Looking at the "Brett Walker" solution u can define ur toArray(dict) method and passing its result to uiDialog. e.g.:   uiDialog(toArray({url:MyURL, data:null, methid:'GET'}), false);

Comment: i know that how can i achieve it in one line

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new Array(3);
arr['url']=MyURL;
arr['data']=null;
arr['method']='GET';

uiDialog(arr,false);
```

Comment: As far as I known it is not possible. Sorry.