# Pass associative array to javascript function in a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, associative-array, jquery-1.9

I am trying to pass associative array to functions in a jquery plugin. Just as the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888921/pass-associative-array-to-javascript-function).

And this is my plugin and how I execute it on dom ready. You can have a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKKGQ/).

The plugin works fine on firefox only but fails on chrome, opera and safari. I don't understand why!

In chrome, the javascript console says there are two errors in these lines,

an error in the plugin, error message,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
// Callback function for proccesing the result.
$this.get_result = function({object:object,setup:setup,data:xml}) {...
```

and another error in dom ready,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
beforeAjax: function({setup:setup,object:form}) {...
```

Can somebody tell me what I have done incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax errors ....

```
    // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
        var defaults = {
            setup:                  {},
            beforeAjax:             function() {},
            onAjaxSuccess:          function() {},
            onError:                function() {},
            onSuccess:              function() {}
        //  }  // <--- Extra bracket
        };   // <-- should have semi colon
```

defaults object has extra curly bracket ... should really have semi colon after  var declaration

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the answer. i updated it but still get the same errors... http://jsfiddle.net/sKKGQ/1/